# Problem: If $f\in L^1[0,1]$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x+\frac{k}{n})=\int_0^1 f(s)ds$ in $L^1[0,1]$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is the solution from the Prof.:
Define $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x+\frac{k}{n})$. Then, unless $j<n$, we get $\hat f_n(j)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i j k/n} \hat f(j)=0$ for $j\not=0$, while $\hat f_n(0)=\hat f(0)=\int_0^1f(s)ds.$ By the uniqueness of Fourier coefficients, $f_n(x)=\hat f(0)$ a.e. on $[0,1]$.

I don't understand the part "unless $j<n$". Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(e^{2\pi i j/n)^k}=\frac{1-e^{2\pi ij}}{1-e^{(2\pi ij)/n}}$ and $e^{2\pi ij}=1$, we get only problems if $j=0$ or $\frac{j}{n}\in\mathbb{Z^*}$. Shouldn't it therefore be "unless $j>n$?. And where do I need the limit $n\to\infty$?

Comment: only refering to your question in the title: do you maybe mean "for allmost-every $x$"? otherwise for each $x$ you can easily change $f$ on countably many points, such that each summand on the left lide equals $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I think he means for a.e. $x$!